# Why PowerVM LPAR CPU utilization is negative

Tags: virtual-machine, aix, cpu

For a specific case I compute an PowerVM LPAR CPU utilization to be a large number less than zero.

I am fetching the lpar sample event using:

```
lslparutil -r lpar -m P750 --filter "lpar_names=i5lp5" -n 2
```

The output is:

```
time=12/11/2013 14:05:19,event_type=sample,resource_type=lpar,sys_time=12/11/2013 02:06:18,time_cycles=1972174181699073,lpar_name=i5lp5,lpar_id=16,curr_proc_mode=ded,curr_procs=1,curr_sharing_mode=share_idle_procs,curr_5250_cpw_percent=0.0,mem_mode=ded,curr_mem=2048,entitled_cycles=850096297330210,capped_cycles=850096297330210,uncapped_cycles=0,shared_cycles_while_active=0,idle_cycles=847094465568064,run_latch_instructions=761582721233,run_latch_cycles=1504048749490
time=12/11/2013 14:04:19,event_type=sample,resource_type=lpar,sys_time=12/11/2013 02:05:18,time_cycles=1972143333868079,lpar_name=i5lp5,lpar_id=16,curr_proc_mode=ded,curr_procs=1,curr_sharing_mode=share_idle_procs,curr_5250_cpw_percent=0.0,mem_mode=ded,curr_mem=2048,entitled_cycles=850065449497618,capped_cycles=850065449497618,uncapped_cycles=0,shared_cycles_while_active=0,idle_cycles=839855392690628,run_latch_instructions=761562942327,run_latch_cycles=1503980657960
```

As per the [lslparutil manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/index.jsp?topic=/p7edm/lslparutil.html) the formula to compute processor utilization for dedicated partitions is

```
Processor utilization % = ((capped_cycles - idle_cycles) / capped_cycles) * 100
```

The relevant information from the above output are:

```
time=12/11/2013 14:05:19, capped_cycles=850096297330210, idle_cycles=847094465568064
time=12/11/2013 14:04:19, capped_cycles=850065449497618, idle_cycles=839855392690628
```

Therefore the result will be as follows:

```
(((850096297330210 - 850065449497618) - (847094465568064 - 839855392690628))/(850096297330210 - 850065449497618))*100
```

equals to: `−23367.038910583`

Why the percentage value is negative.

Note the idle cycle difference is `(847094465568064 - 839855392690628) = 7.239072877×10¹²` which is much much higher than the capped cycle difference.

Where as the time cycle difference is `(1972174181699073−1972143333868079) = 30847830994`

The lpar is in Running state:

```
lssyscfg -r lpar -m P750 --filter "lpar_names=i5lp5" -F name state

i5lp5 Running
```

Can anyone help me with this, what is wrong? This formula works for other LPARs in the system. Is the computation process has an error or is it something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

The formula you used is the one for partitions with dedicated processors. Their capped cycles is essentially always equal to their "entitled" cycles.

For shared processor LPARs, the formula is:

> Processor utilization % = ((capped_cycles + uncapped_cycles) / entitled_cycles) * 100

That can go above 100% if the LPAR goes over its entitled CPU usage, depending on settings and available CPU cycles. (For processor units, divide by `time_cycles` instead.)

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the problem is the result is negative percentage value in this case.

Comment: The result is negative because your calculation doesn't make sense for an LPAR with shared CPUs. The calculation works for the dedicated case because `capped_cycles` == total cycles available (nearly). So the percentage is `100*used_cycles/total_cycles` == `100*(capped-idle)/capped`. In shared mode, `capped_cycles` does not represent total cycles available at all, so that equation makes no sense there.

Comment: That is right, although it is not mentioned in the question, the lpar was a dedicated processor lpar and that is why I asked the question. I am not considering lpars with shared cpu for the formula i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Could you please update your question then? Please add at least the `sharing_mode` attribute and maybe the processor settings (desired/min/max procs and proc units)

Comment: Seems a bit difficult to find the system right now. I will get back once I am able to trace down the system.